# Nimble matching of struct via "identical to"

Tags: swift, unit-testing, xctest, quick-nimble

I am using nimble in unit test expectation mapping and having a question about comparing structs.

What i am observing is that the matched `.to(be(x))` does not work at all with structs. So this following unit test fails:

```
func someTest() {
    struct Struct {
        let a: String
        let b: String
    }
    let structure = Struct(a: "a", b: "b")
    expect(structure).to(be(structure))
}
```

Does this mean that the copy on write mechanism kicks in here and we are looking on 2 copies? Why is that test failing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `be()` function actually calls `beIdenticalTo`, which uses pointer equality checking, so it only works for reference types. See the [BeIdenticalTo source code](https://github.com/Quick/Nimble/blob/e28ac62c8c069cb95a6954045ea10baeae5c2dcc/Sources/Nimble/Matchers/BeIdenticalTo.swift#L32).

You should make `Struct` conform to `Equatable` and use `equal` instead.

```
func someTest() {
    struct Struct: Equatable {
        let a: String
        let b: String
    }
    let structure = Struct(a: "a", b: "b")
    expect(structure).to(equal(structure))
}
```

Comment: Ah, is it possible with nimble to actually compare the address where the pointer is pointing to?

Comment: @MartinMlostek that's not the Swift way of testing and especially not value types. You could use `RawPointer`s, but really - you shouldn't. With value types you should never care about object equality on the memory level - you should only care about the properties being equal.

Comment: I agree, i was just curious in that small example to play around (and actually learn) the copy-on-write behavior

Comment: @MartinMlostek there's no copy-on-write behaviour in your example. Copy-on-write is an extra optimisation only implemented by some built-in types (such as `Array` and `Dictionary`). For custom types, you'd need to implement it yourself. By default, value types are copied on each assignment, not only when mutating them. You don't mutate `structure`, so if there was copy-on-write, your test would pass.

Comment: But copy on write is also implemented in `String` right? This means assigning `let structureB = structure` would not lead to a duplication of the struct, am i correct? (sorry for going offtopic)

Comment: I am not familiar with Nimble, but I wonder if that is a side-effect of the (in)famous “anything can be cast to an object” – both structs are wrapped in (seperate) `SwiftValue` objects.

Comment: @MartinMlostek yes, but there's no write operation on any of the `String`. And you are testing the parent `struct` itself, which doesn't implement copy-on-write, so it doesn't matter if its properties by themselves do implement it.

Comment: Copy-on-write really has absolutely nothing to do with structs. It just so happens that all the CoW types in the standard library happen to be structs. It's a manually implemented pattern, that could just as easily be implemented on a class. In the case of assignment of `String`, there's absolutely nothing unusual happening. Strings are structs, and the struct is copied into the new variable. But the string struct is only 3 machine words (IIRC). All of the actual character data is stored in a heap-allocated buffer. That buffer is what's copied on mutation (if there's no other owning references